# Convergence of a composite trigonometric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was asked to determine the convergence of following series.$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\tan(\sin n)}{n^3}$$
It seems comparison test doesn't work since the terms can be negative. I also try root test and ratio test. But the calculations of limit are a bit too complicated due to two trigonometric functions there. Any hint about this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $-1 \le \sin n \le 1$, we have $|\tan(\sin n)| \le \tan(1)$ as $|\tan(x)|$ is increasing on $[0, 1]$ and decreasing on $[-1, 0]$  . Consequently,
$$
\frac{|\tan(\sin n)|}{n^3} \le \frac{\tan(1)}{n^3}.
$$
Hence your series converges absolutely by comparison with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\tan(1)}{n^3}$, and thus converges.

Comment: Thx! I just realised the terms are non-negative because of the range of sin n!

Comment: @Bobby : No.  $\tan(\sin(4)) < 0$.  It is however the case that $-\tan(1) = \tan(-1) \leq \tan\sin(n)) \leq \tan(1)$.

Comment: @EricTowers Oh... So I cannot apply comparison test?

Comment: The direct comparison test requires $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$ to compare the series $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$.  SO that test does not resolve $\sum_n \tan(\sin(n))$.  However, it's possible that $\sum_n \tan(\sin(n))$ is absolutely convergent, by the direct comparison test, which would tell you whether $\sum_n \tan(\sin(n))$ is convergent.

Comment: @EricTowers I got it! Thx!